# RestTemplate HTTS & Choosing the Client Certificate

Tags: spring, client-certificates, spring-web, jsse, ssl-client-authentication

Can someone help me understand how to use HTTPS mutual authentication such that I can programmatically choose which client certificate to use during authentication?

Here is the context of the question.  I am using:

- A JKS containing multiple client certificates
- Apache SSLContextBuilder to create the SslContext
- Apache HttpClients to create a CloseableHttpClient
- Spring HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to create the RestTemplate

The approach I'm taking is similar to [Java Rest call with different user certs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065133/java-rest-call-with-different-user-certs)
 and [Spring Boot SSL Client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776194).  In neither of these examples do I see where the specific alias within the KeyStore is specified.

How can I have an application that initiates multiple mutual HTTPS connections using a distinct client certificate for each connection?

Comment: Here are few trivial PrivateKeyStrategy implementations that may help?:
- [Lambda](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-client/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/client/DropwizardSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java#L95)
-[Anonymous Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37775765/1029971)
-[Class](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/won/cryptography/ssl/predefinedaliasprivatekeystrategy.html)
-[testClientAuthSSLAliasChoice](http://svn.jetbrains.org/teamcity/sandbox/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/test/java/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TestSSLSocketFactory.java)